# Object mock using data factory guy addon

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, ember-data

I am new to Embebr js and using ember-data-factory addon to mock ajax response however having trouble mocking below response.

```
 {
      "employee/profile": {
        "id": 60799,
        "gender": "Male",
        "fname": "Mick",
        "lname": "Hussey",
        "addresses": [
          "50345"      
        ]   
      },
      "employee/addresses": [
        {
          "id": "50345",
          "addressState": "GA",
          "zip": "30004"  
        }     
      ] 

    }
```

To achieve this i have created both profile and address model  in tests/factories/ directory. 
**employee/profile Model**

```
import FactoryGuy from 'ember-data-factory-guy';

FactoryGuy.define('employee/profile', {
  default: {    
    id: 60799,
    gender: 'Male',
    fname: 'Mick',
    lname: 'Hussey',
    addresses:  FactoryGuy.hasMany('employee/address')  
  } 
});
```

**Address Model:**

```
import FactoryGuy from 'ember-data-factory-guy';

FactoryGuy.define('employee/address', {
  default: {   
    id: '50345',
    addressState: 'GA',
    zip: '300014'   
    employee: FactoryGuy.belongsTo('employee/profile'),

  }
});
```

And when i try to build profile object using below code snippet, all the fields except addresses is getting populated.

```
let profile = this.build('employee/profile');
```

can anybody please  help me understand whats going wrong.

Thanks
Gautam

Comment: is that a typo, You have 'employee/address' somewhere and 'employee/addresses'. May be that is causing the problem

Comment: sorry that was while drafting question.corrected

Comment: I have not used the above addon. Although I know, for your hasMany attribute to get populated, it should already have the relationship data. So when you do `let profile = this.build('customer/profile');` will it populate store with `employee/address` also? or may be you have to do it independently.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I tried with both but still not able to ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the relationship as follows:

```
addresses:  FactoryGuy.hasMany('employee/address', 1)
```

This way you indicate that you want an array of addresses with just one item in it. If you omit the last one, you will end up with an empty list of addresses. Please see the source code of `hasMany` in [github](https://github.com/danielspaniel/ember-data-factory-guy/blob/master/addon/factory-guy.js).

By the way, I have prepared you a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/6dbad5e7857163eb20371b6dceac927c?openFiles=tests.factories.employee.address.js%2C) in case you need it. I am not an expert; but I did my best. You can check factory definitions and unit test for `profile` model under `unit/models/emoloyee/profile-test.js`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, marking as Answer.In addition to your change I had to remove employee: FactoryGuy.belongsTo('employee/profile') from address model.